# Jetty hangs with 100% CPU on sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)

Tags: http, file-upload, amazon-ec2, request, jetty

(update: it has nothing to do with file upload, more details at the bottom)

I'm running **jetty-distribution-9.0.6.v20130930** server over **jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64**, running on **EC2 linux** server. It's a backend to a mobile app that receives about 50k requests/day.

About once a day, a thread hangs with 100% CPU, until I kill it (after running several hours on 100% CPU).

JavaMelody shows the following call stack for the hung thread:

[image]

Jetty HTTP connector definition, from etc/jetty-https.xml:

```
<Call id="httpsConnector" name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
      <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                <Arg name="sslContextFactory"><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="sslHttpConfig"/></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.https.port" default="8443" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout">30000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

Jetty HTTPS configuration, from start.ini:

```
jetty.https.port=8443
etc/jetty-https.xml
```

JVM version -

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.4.3.2.32.amzn1-x86_64 u45-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

a

**Questions**

1. What causes this?
2. Why timeouts are not triggered to kill these hanging threads?
3. How do I enable timeout of such scenarios?

**Update**

Turns out it has nothing to do with file upload, it sometimes happens also in a different EC2 server (same configuration), and sometimes the two instances hang at **exactly the same time**, with the same call stack.

The other server doesn't implement file upload, so this option is ruled out.

Comment: The `ChannelEndpoint.fill()` means the server is attempting to read from the connection. (the next line shows that you are also using SSL).

So that means your stuck thread is the one for `etc/jetty-https.xml` not `etc/jetty-http.xml`.  You didn't paste that configuration.

Comment: Please include the specific versions of Jetty and the JVM

Comment: Added. jetty-distribution-9.0.6.v20130930 running on /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64.

Comment: the path to your java is not specific enough to know the major / minor / update / build versions for your installation of java. (use `$ java -version`) - that path information only gets you major/minor and architecture

Comment: Since you are using SSL, you *have to stay up to date* with your JVM.  Currently update 40 or 45. (and update 40 expires on Dec 10th)

Comment: Version added to the OP. It seems to be the latest, 45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was resolved in both servers after upgrading to **Jetty 9.3** and **Java 8**.

Up until then, both servers (with two different web apps) had this happening almost every day around 6:00-7:00 PM, these are the incoming traffic's pick hours.

**UPDATE**

The cause was a burst of opened database connections which exhausted the connection pool, it caused some threads in the server to hang.

So it has nothing to do with upload, but it may be a Jetty or Java bug that hang threads instead of rejecting new connections.

This explains why it happened on two different servers, they were both connected to the same RD2 instance, which has exhausted its connection pool.

Answer (score 2):

You have a 30 second timeout configured, and a Mime / File-Upload in progress from a mobile device.

With a perceived stuck thread.  Since you are working with mobile clients, and servlet 3.0, you should look into dropping the use of Apache Commons File Upload and just using the default Servlet 3.0 [HttpServletRequest.getParts()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) logic.  This will allow Jetty itself to manage slow or problematic clients (which is extremely common in mobile client and their mobile networks), using various async I/O techniques available to it.

Apache Commons File Upload uses older techniques that require the server to switch over to blocking mode I/O, which for slow clients would mean that the blocking I/O behavior would cause a long duration selector spin with a trickle of bytes never actually tripping over the idle timeout (as technically speaking the connection isn't idle, there's still traffic, but at excruciatingly slow speeds)

Your choices:

1. Since you say this is a mobile App (and not a mobile browser), switch from `POST` with file upload (and all of the associated mime `multipart/form-data` nonsense that you don't need) to `PUT` with file upload (which is a simpler request content-type) just to avoid the Apache Commons File-Upload layer.  Of course, this would require an App update.
2. Upgrade and/or reconfigure your server side implementation to use Servlet 3.0 (for Jetty 9.0.6) or Servlet 3.1 (for Jetty 9.1.0) standard techniques for Request multi-part content, with the goal of eliminating the Apache Commons File Upload library.  This would be a server side only update.
3. Add a filter in front of your file upload servlets that specifies an overall upper limit on how long the request should take, killing the connection if it takes too long.
4. Completely change up how you do file uploads from your app, don't use POST, put lower limits on performance, if the upload takes too long, fail, notify the user, give them an option to defer the upload till they are on wifi, etc. (some apps even have configuration options to upload content such as "on mobile or wifi" vs "only on wifi")

Comment: @Kof - did this help you with your issue? We've been struggling w/ a similar issue and were curious to see how you made out.

Comment: Still haven't got the chance to implement this. It happens rarely, so it has low priority.

Comment: This is not because of file upload, please read update in OP.